# Print () result is not output, can't find error

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, hashlib

This script generates a hash, but somewhere it did not correctly write something in the function.

```
from bitcoin import *
import os
import hashlib
import base58
 

while True:
    priv =  random_key()
    pubkey = privtopub(priv)
    compress_pubkey = False
    
 
    if (compress_pubkey):
        if (ord(pubkey[-2:].decode('hex')) % 2 == 0):
            pubkey_compressed = '02'
        else:
            pubkey_compressed = '03'
        pubkey_compressed += pubkey[2:66]
        hex_str = bytearray.fromhex(pubkey_compressed)
    else:
        hex_str = bytearray.fromhex(pubkey)
 
key_hash = hash160(hex_str)

def hash160(hex_str):
    sha = hashlib.sha256()
    rip = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    sha.update(hex_str)
    rip.update( sha.digest() )
    print ( "key_hash = \t" + rip.hexdigest() )
    return rip.hexdigest()  # .hexdigest() is hex ASCII
```

I checked the script to work. Did `print (pubkey)`. The public keys are displayed as a result, but I don't need to get key_hash. Unfortunately when I do   `print ("key_hash = \ t" + rip.hexdigest ())`

The result is not executed! I don't know programming. Help fix the code!

Comment: Well, you are calling `hash160` before you define it

Comment: Note that you are calling `hash160()` *before* you actually defined that function.  The only way this code could have actually run without error is if one of your imports (would have had to be `bitcoin`) brought in its own function of that name; that version of `hash160()` obviously does not contain the `print` statement.

Comment: @Carcigenicate What needs to be done to display the result?

Comment: @jasonharper How and what do I need to change in hash160 ()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After code rearrangement:

```
from bitcoin import *
import os
import hashlib
import base58

def hash160(hex_str):
    sha = hashlib.sha256()
    rip = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    sha.update(hex_str)
    rip.update(sha.digest())
    print("key_hash = \t" + rip.hexdigest())
    return rip.hexdigest()  # .hexdigest() is hex ASCII

while True:
    priv = random_key()
    pubkey = privtopub(priv)
    compress_pubkey = False

    if (compress_pubkey):
        if (ord(pubkey[-2:].decode('hex')) % 2 == 0):
            pubkey_compressed = '02'
        else:
            pubkey_compressed = '03'
        pubkey_compressed += pubkey[2:66]
        hex_str = bytearray.fromhex(pubkey_compressed)
    else:
        hex_str = bytearray.fromhex(pubkey)

    key_hash = hash160(hex_str)
```

Output:

```
key_hash =  b0ac6f690633331af487f594dd3c42c6c67ce085
key_hash =  de735b3046545f63c8cb2f7d44b7f24a8b769ad7
key_hash =  49b0ae2b541832797680b977ca9e374d1a621787
key_hash =  ea3e1d9762331e791412e96b2a67f418cfd6ca2c
key_hash =  e5ff3affd4ba7eb2bb343548f587bde9dbdace6b
key_hash =  b1a952405516abe494e7e32610a3eaf85d7914f2
key_hash =  a0050e1f18b2d0738c458e237a447bd8f2810fec
key_hash =  23eeca93355ba511bdf28c475b5e62d2da64546b
key_hash =  cc5904bae39ee51b75097c95ad0307a21ecef1bc
... And So On
```

Note that there is an infinity loop (`while True`), consider replacing with a specific number of iterations.